# Is there a way to look for specific websites based on the author?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I'm trying to find a way to search for pages that are built by the same author/ company.

I'm currently using google to look for specific websites for research. So far I managed to do a work around a basically copied pasted the footer of one of the sites under quotation marks, example: "Site built with site builder.", giving me pretty much all the sites with that specific footer. Now, I've come across websites with no footer or anything on it to relate them with, inspecting the site's elements I was trying to find similarities in the  tag but I'm uncertain if it is even possible to search with these parameters as a clause. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a backlink check for whatever site you are looking up. That will probably be the easiest way. You could use search operators to try and turn up some more sites. Check the source code and see if you can find something in there that is unique.

If you are looking for a list of sites running a specific CMS or software you can use [BuiltWith](https://builtwith.com) to do that and filter it.

Answer (score 0):

No.   The web (ie HTTP/HTTPS) does not work like that - from a protocol level there is no required database - ie nothing you can match as a clause - you are only looking at the content of the page.

For the sake of clarity, there may be some meta-data - like the server that was used and headers added by a specific application, but these are fairly arbitrary and usually unrelated to the content of the site.  Similarly, there may be other hints/commonalities within various frameworks, but these are determined by the framework - not by the protocol.